# React props out of date in event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, this

We are building a React-Redux web app that will display multiple Three JS scenes. These scenes come in pairs, and each pair will have synchronized zooming. To facilitate that, we're storing camera data in the Redux store.

Here is our React class (take a deep breath, it's a little long for a SO question), which uses [react-three-renderer](https://github.com/toxicFork/react-three-renderer) to produce Three JS objects:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Vector3 } from 'three';
import React3 from 'react-three-renderer';
import ReferenceGrid from './ReferenceGridVisual';
import ResourceGroup from './resourceGroups/ResourceGroup';
import { initializeRayCastScene } from './viewportMath/RayCastScene';
import zoomCamera from './viewportMath/CameraZoom';
import { registerCamera, zoom } from './actions/cameraActions';
import { InitThreeJsDomEvents, UpdateDomCamera } from './domUtility/ThreeJSDom';

class ThreeJsScene extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.ZoomAmount = 150;
    this.ZoomMaxCap = 1000;
    this.ZoomMinCap = 6;
    this.zoomPadding = 10;
    this.minimumZoom = 45;
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    initializeRayCastScene();

    this.props.registerCamera(this.props.sceneName);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle
    InitThreeJsDomEvents(this.camera, this.canvas._canvas);
  }

  onWheel = (event) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    this.zoom(event.clientX, event.clientY, event.deltaY);
  }

  setCameraRef = (camera) => {
    UpdateDomCamera(camera);
    this.camera = camera;
  }

  zoom(screenPosX, screenPosY, zoomAmount) {
    const size = {
      width: this.props.width,
      height: this.props.height,
    };
    const result = zoomCamera(screenPosX, screenPosY, zoomAmount, this.camera.position,
      size, this.props.distance, this.camera, this.props.cameraType, this.ZoomMaxCap,
      this.ZoomMinCap);
    this.ZoomAmount = (result.ZoomAmount) ? result.ZoomAmount : this.ZoomAmount;
    this.props.zoom(this.props.sceneName, result.distanceChangeFactor, result.newCameraPosition);
  }

  render() {
    let position;
    if (this.props.cameraPosition != null) {
      position = new Vector3(
        this.props.cameraPosition.x,
        this.props.cameraPosition.y,
        this.props.cameraPosition.z
      );
    } else {
      position = new Vector3();
    }
    const left = -this.props.width / 2;
    const right = this.props.width / 2;
    const top = this.props.height / 2;
    const bottom = -this.props.height / 2;

    return (
      <div
        style={{ lineHeight: '0' }}
        onWheel={this.onWheel}
      >
        <React3
          width={this.props.width}
          height={this.props.height}
          mainCamera="camera"
          antialias
          pixelRatio={1}
          ref={(canvas) => { this.canvas = canvas; }}
        >
          <scene ref={(scene) => { this.scene = scene; }}>
            <orthographicCamera
              name="camera"
              left={left}
              right={right}
              top={top}
              bottom={bottom}
              near={0.01}
              far={1400}
              position={position}
              ref={this.setCameraRef}
            />
            <ambientLight
              color={0xaaaaaa}
            />
            <directionalLight
              color={0xaaaaaa}
              intensity={1.1}
              position={new Vector3(3, 4, 10)}
              lookAt={new Vector3(0, 0, 0)}
            />
            <ReferenceGrid xActive yActive zActive={false} store={this.props.store} />
            <ResourceGroup store={this.props.store}>
              {this.props.children}
            </ResourceGroup>
          </scene>
        </React3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const ownCamera = state.cameras.get(ownProps.sceneName);
  if (ownCamera == null) {
    console.log('own camera null');
    return { cameraAvailable: false };
  }
  console.log('has own camera');
  const cameraPosition = ownCamera.position;
  const cameraType = ownCamera.type;
  const distance = ownCamera.distance;
  return {
    cameraAvailable: true,
    cameraPosition,
    cameraType,
    distance,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  registerCamera: (cameraName) => {
    dispatch(registerCamera(cameraName));
  },
  zoom: (cameraName, factor, newCameraPosition) => {
    dispatch(zoom(cameraName, factor, newCameraPosition));
  },
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ThreeJsScene);
```

Additionally, for reference, here are the action creators:

```
export const registerCamera = cameraName => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: 'REGISTER_CAMERA', newCameraName: cameraName });
};

export const zoom = (cameraName, factor, newCameraPosition) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const state = getState();
  const zoomFactor = state.cameras.get(cameraName).distance * (1 - factor);
  dispatch({ type: 'CAMERA_ZOOM', cameraName, factor: zoomFactor, newCameraPosition });
};
```

And the reducer:

```
import { Map } from 'immutable';

const defaultCameraProperties = {
  distance: 150,
  type: 'orthogonal',
  position: { x: 0, y: 10, z: 50 },
  rotation: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, w: 1 },
};

const initialState = Map();

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'REGISTER_CAMERA': {
      const newCamera = {
        ...defaultCameraProperties,
        ...action.newCameraProperties,
      };
      return state.set(action.newCameraName, newCamera);
    }

    case 'CAMERA_ZOOM': {
      const updatedDistance = action.factor;
      const updatedCameraPosition = {
        ...state.get(action.cameraName).position,
        ...action.newCameraPosition,
      };
      const updatedCamera = {
        ...state.get(action.cameraName),
        position: updatedCameraPosition,
        distance: updatedDistance,
      };
      return state.set(action.cameraName, updatedCamera);
    }

    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
};
```

The challenge is in the `zoom` function in the React class, the React `props` are not what I would expect, and therefore zooming is failing. Here is a summary of the sequence of relevant events as I understand them:

1. `componentWillMount` is called, which dispatches the `REGISTER_CAMERA` method. (We do this rather than having camera data by default in the store because these pairs of scenes are generated dynamically - there is not a static number of them.)
2. The React `render` method is called.
3. The React `render` method is called again since the `REGISTER_CAMERA` action has now modified the store and we have new props - the camera related props are now available.
4. I trigger zoom with my mouse wheel. The `onWheel` handler calls the `zoom` function, but breakpointing in that method reveals that the camera related props - like `this.props.cameraType` - are `undefined`. The React props appear as they do in 2. (`zoomCamera` does some calculations. Since these properties are unavailable, zooming fails.)

I can't figure out why this is. My suspicion is I'm misunderstanding something about what `this` context is bound to the zoom method.

In short my question is why are my `props` not up to date and how can I make the updated version available to the `zoom` function?

Comment: Does `zoom(screenPosX, screenPosY, zoomAmount)` get executed after you do the wheel movement?

Comment: @Dez Correct, note how the `<div>` has an `onWheel` attribute that calls `this.onWheel`, which then calls `zoom`.

Comment: I meant, have you checked it indeed does get executed? I don't see how it is bound to `this` anywhere in your code.

Comment: @Dez I am able to breakpoint in the `zoom` function upon using my mouse wheel. Changing it to be a property initializer does not seem to make a difference. @Tony The `props` in the `zoom` function are such that `cameraAvailable` is `false` (see `mapStateToProps`). I expect `cameraAvailable` to be `true`, as well as the other props that are set in the second half of `mapStateToProps` to be present.

Comment: I had an @Tony tell me about `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)` which helped me with states, props not updating.

Comment: @Pocketninja I added `componentDidUpdate` just to breakpoint and see what the `props` were, both for the `prevProps` and `this.props`. In that method it is as I expect as well, `this.props.cameraAvailable` is `true` and the camera related props are there. But still when I trigger the zoom with my mousewheel it is the props that match `prevProps`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an error with hot module reloading. Running our build cold does not exhibit the issue.